# Would you please throw a light on "with whom VS. with who"?

Tags: relative-clauses

Would you show me if they mean the same thing? or, which one is incorrect?

A. Whom did you go with?

B. Who did you go with?

Comment: Just FYI, the "with" in C and D is redundant. It should be "with who/whom did you go."

Comment: Though ＊"With who did you go?" is ungrammatical.  ("Who did you go with?" is fine.)

Comment: "With whom did you go?" -- if you want to use "whom", place the preposition before it (consider it a rule). In America, at least in daily English, "whom" is hardly ever used. Almost never. B is correct.